# python mechanize problem with selectcontrol

Tags: python, list, screen-scraping, mechanize, asterisk

basically one of the select controls has a few "options" in which to choose from

if i use:

```
for t in br.forms():
        print t
```

the output i get is

```
`SelectControl(ctl00$cph2$ddlSchool=[*2])
 SelectControl(ctl00$cph2$ddlMarkingPeriod=[*1, 2, 3, 4])
 SelectControl(ctl00$cph2$ddlCourseSection=[*1120:01:1, 1515:01:1, 2445:01:1, 3723:02:1, 4140:03:1, 5100:08:1, 1:01:1, 9970:07:1, 9913:01:1])>
 SubmitControl(ctl00$cph2$btnExecuteReport=Execute) (readonly)`
```

notice the asterisks

now, what i want is to store the list under "ctl00$cph2$ddlCourseSection" in my program but if i try and store it and then print it:

```
save = br.form['ctl00$cph2$ddlCourseSection'] 
print save
```

the output i get is:

```
['1120:01:1']
```

instead of:

```
['1120:01:1', '1515:01:1', '2445:01:1', '3723:02:1', '4140:03:1', '5100:08:1', '1:01:1', '9970:07:1', '9913:01:1']
```

so how would i be able to save all of the elements of the list rather than just the element with the asterisk next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this you only get the default value.

```
save = br.form['ctl00$cph2$ddlCourseSection'] 
print save
```

To get all values you have to use

```
save = br.form.possible_items('ctl00$cph2$ddlCourseSection')
print save
```

i didn't test it but i think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to assign multiple values to a single-select form field. You would have to have a multi-select to do that successfully. The asterisk indicates the selected element, the non-asterisk'd items are the other options in the list. Are you sure that you are working with a multi-select and not a normal select box? The form will not allow you to select multiple values for a single select.

Comment: so do a for loop, going through all the selected items and appending to a list?

Comment: I guess it depends on your intention. What are you trying to do?